# Python Altair - Setting Minimum Bar Height for Interactive Graphs

Tags: python, data-visualization, vega-lite, altair

I am currently generating an interactive stacked-bar graph, where individual stacks of the bar graph can be clicked on to update other graphics.

The issue I am running into is a problem of scale.  Sometimes, I will have a dataset where 1 bar has a reading of 25,000, and another will have a reading of 1.

It becomes near impossible to see, let alone click, that entry of 1, when the scale goes up so high due to another reading.

Is it possible to set a "minimum" height for any bar piece? I know this is likely difficult or weird due to Y-axis scaling then.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems like that would become misleading when trying to interpret the data. Would it make more sense instead to increase the size of the area you can click instead of increasing the size of the bar? Alternatively, you could just switch to a log scale when the disparity reaches a certain threshold.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was thinking as well.  It'll be jarring between the two, but I suppose I could always just generate both and can reference whichever one is easier to work with at a given time.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strokeWidth` to draw the edge:

```
import altair as alt

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=["a", "b"], y=[1, 1000]))
select = alt.selection(type="single", fields=["x"], empty="none")
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar(strokeWidth=5).encode(
    y="x",
    x="y",
    fill=alt.condition(select, alt.value("red"), alt.value("blue")),
    stroke=alt.condition(select, alt.value("red"), alt.value("blue")),
).add_selection(select)
```

if you don't want to show the stroke, you can set `strokeOpacity=0.001`.

```
import altair as alt

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=["a", "b"], y=[1, 1000]))
select = alt.selection(type="single", fields=["x"], empty="none")
alt.Chart(df).mark_bar(strokeWidth=5, stroke="red", strokeOpacity=0.001).encode(
    y="x",
    x="y",
    fill=alt.condition(select, alt.value("red"), alt.value("blue")),
).add_selection(select).interactive()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set a minimum bar height in Altair or Vega-Lite, short of modifying the input data which may be misleading.

Perhaps you could concatenate another chart with a shared axis, and provide interaction via that instead? for example:

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': list('ABCDE'),
    'y': [1, 2, 3, 10000, 500]
})

selector = alt.selection_single(fields=['x'])
color = alt.condition(selector, alt.value('steelblue'), alt.value('lightgray'))

base = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
    color=color
).add_selection(
    selector
)

bars = base.encode(
    x=alt.X('x:N', axis=None),
    y='y:Q',
)

rects = base.encode(
    x='x:N'
)

alt.vconcat(bars, rects).configure_concat(spacing=0)
```

[image]